# How to restore tqdm progress bar after disconnect remote server

Tags: python, remote-server, tqdm

I have remote Ubuntu sever with running Python iteration process on it, which was launched using ssh connected jupyter lab. To monitor progress I added "tqdm" widget to this iterations loop in my JupyterLab notebook on my host machine:

```
for idx, data in tqdm(enumerate(dataloader), disable = silence):
```

Sometimes connection to remote server losts and my progress bar freezes forever, but process is still runing on remote sever (I can see it in htop). I'm wonder is there "in-box" option in tqdm to handle such situations and continue "progressbar" progress (let's say we can log to file our progress info and when connection restore - just load info from this log file)

Comment: may be `tmux` or `screen` ?

Comment: @BrownBear What exactly do you suggest? I'm already using tmux

Comment: sorry I missed that point, then I haven't ideas.